# Why is log output twice using app.get() and app.use()?

Tags: javascript, express

I have a very basic Express web server:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    console.log('GET');
});

app.param('user', function(req, res, next, id) {
    console.log('PARAM');
    next();
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When I run `http://localhost:3000/MyName`, I have the following output in my console:

```
PARAM
GET
PARAM
GET
```

Why do I get every output twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser most likely sent a second request on its own in order to get the favicon (`http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico`).

Comment: Yes, that is probably the reason. I did not think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Amberlamps You can easily display all requests with the "logger" middleware: `app.use(express.logger());`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will definitly try that.